# Delayed Job: Delayed job task hangs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am using delayed job to perform background jobs. i am running delayed jobs with command `RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job -n 5 start`

when i starts delayed job and checked the delayed jobs it show that jobs are running. when i checked the delayed job again after 1 hour delayed jobs status for all job was still  "running". All jobs was supposed to completed in 15 minutes but even after 1 hour it is showing status as running. please help.

Below is my delayed job log file content.

```
I, [2015-12-22T13:10:56.463154 #15255]  INFO -- : 2015-12-22T13:10:56+0000: [Worker(delayed_job.0 host:ip-172-31-6-58 pid:15255)] Job QrCodeGenerator (id=16) RUNNING
I, [2015-12-22T13:10:56.467157 #15261]  INFO -- : 2015-12-22T13:10:56+0000: [Worker(delayed_job.1 host:ip-172-31-6-58 pid:15261)] Job QrCodeGenerator (id=17) RUNNING
I, [2015-12-22T13:10:56.544987 #15267]  INFO -- : 2015-12-22T13:10:56+0000: [Worker(delayed_job.2 host:ip-172-31-6-58 pid:15267)] Job QrCodeGenerator (id=15) RUNNING
```

status of jobs that are running are as below.

```
 => #<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job id: 15, priority: 0, attempts: 0, handler: "--- !ruby/struct:QrCodeGenerator\nclient: !ruby/obj...", last_error: nil, run_at: "2015-12-22 11:57:28", locked_at: "2015-12-22 13:10:56", failed_at: nil, locked_by: "delayed_job.2 host:ip-172-31-6-58 pid:15267", queue: nil, created_at: "2015-12-22 09:07:39", updated_at: "2015-12-22 11:57:51">
2.0.0-p598 :004 >

 => #<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job id: 16, priority: 0, attempts: 0, handler: "--- !ruby/struct:QrCodeGenerator\nclient: !ruby/obj...", last_error: nil, run_at: "2015-12-22 09:08:06", locked_at: "2015-12-22 13:10:56", failed_at: nil, locked_by: "delayed_job.0 host:ip-172-31-6-58 pid:15255", queue: nil, created_at: "2015-12-22 09:08:06", updated_at: "2015-12-22 09:08:06">

 => #<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job id: 17, priority: 0, attempts: 0, handler: "--- !ruby/struct:QrCodeGenerator\nclient: !ruby/obj...", last_error: nil, run_at: "2015-12-22 09:08:44", locked_at: "2015-12-22 13:10:56", failed_at: nil, locked_by: "delayed_job.1 host:ip-172-31-6-58 pid:15261", queue: nil, created_at: "2015-12-22 09:08:44", updated_at: "2015-12-22 09:08:44">
```

my code to insert job in delayed job is as below.

```
QrCodeGenerator = Struct.new(:client,:request,:quantity) do
  def perform
      AuthenticationCode.save_qr_codes(client,request,quantity)
  end

  def error(job, exception)
    if request.status != "completed"
      request.update_attributes(:status => "failed")
    end
  end

  def destroy_failed_jobs?
    true
  end

  def max_attempts
    1
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have enqueued(and start) the job in somewhere else. Thus the problem is just why the job keep running.

I think you should first make sure that processes are indeed initiated/started.

Then, the gem [`delayed_job_web`](https://github.com/ejschmitt/delayed_job_web) is ***a useful interface*** to monitor status of processes.

On the other hand, you can try setting `max_run_time` to see whether `delayed_job` is functioning as expected.

```
# config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb
Delayed::Worker.max_run_time = 5.minutes
```